# Python unnable to build query string

Tags: python, mysql

I'm having trouble with the following code:

```
start_date = dt.datetime(2012,01,01,00,00,00)
end_date = dt.datetime(2014,01,01,00,00,00)

sql="SELECT c.id extension, er.id, flow, filename, filesize, unread, er.cr_date, callerid, \
length, callid, info, party FROM extension_recording er, extension e, client c \
WHERE er.extension_id = e.id AND e.client_id = c.id AND c.parent_client_id = %s \
AND er.cr_date => %s AND er.cr_date <= %s" % (client_id) (start_date) (end_date)

cur.execute(sql)
recordings = cur.fetchall()

if recordings.rowcount == 0: sys.exit("No recordings for selected date range - exiting")

for recording in recordings:
    do stuff to recording
```

Building the query string results in the following error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I'm sure I am missing something blindingly obvious, but I can't see the wood for the trees.

Comment: Why (client_id) (start_date) (end_date)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the end of your long line to this:

```
... er.cr_date <= %s" % (client_id, start_date, end_date)
```

Also, while you are at it, triple-quotes are more convenient for long lines:

```
sql = """
    SELECT c.id extension, ...
    ... er.cr_date <= %s""" % (...
```

Comment: A thousand thanks! Still struggling with Python syntax. Works perfectly.